# I am having an Error in Django Search Views

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views

I am trying to create a search functionality in django. I just wrote the view but i was getting an error with that. I have tried debugging the codes but I don't seems to know where the error is.

Error Log

```
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Alex_SMS\SMS\core\urls.py", line 2, in <module>
    from . import views
  File "C:\Users\Habib\Documents\django\FIVERR\Alex_SMS\SMS\core\views.py", line 37
    return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':      
        product_name =  request.GET.get('search')    
        try:
            product = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=product_name)
            context = {"product": product}
        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
        except:
            product = "What is this"
            context = {"product":product}
    else:
        result = "Sorry there is no product with that name"
        return render(request, "core/search.html", {"result":result})
```

Comment: The hanging `try` block is your problem...

Comment: hanging like how sir

Comment: A `try` block should be followed by an `except` or a `finally` block (It doesn't make sense to just have only a try block anyway). **Edit:** A `try` block should be **directly** followed by an `except` or a `finally` block

Comment: i added an except block but it is still same result. I have updated the question as well.

Comment: Thanks Sir, i was able to solve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to return during a `try/except` which you can't do.

You need to return after this block;

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':      
        product_name =  request.GET.get('search')    
        try:
            product = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=product_name)
            context = {"product": product}
        except:
            product = "What is this"
            context = {"product":product}

        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)

    else:
        result = "Sorry there is no product with that name"
        return render(request, "core/search.html", {"result":result})
```

It's generally considered bad practise to not catch specific exceptions though.

Here's some good information on exception handling; https://wiki.python.org/moin/HandlingExceptions

Comment: Thanks, i was able to figure the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the issue by adding an except block as well as removing the return statement after the try statement and adding to after the except block.

views.py

```
def search(request):
    if request.method == 'GET':      
        product_name =  request.GET.get('search')    
        try:
            product = Product.objects.filter(name__icontains=product_name)
            context = {"product": product}
        except product_name.DoesNotExist:
            product = None
        return render(request, "core/search.html", context)
    else:
        result = "Sorry there is no product with that name"
        return render(request, "core/search.html", {"result":result})
```